# Adding third disk as a single disk in a server with an existing RAID1

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, raid, fedora

I've got a ProLiant DL360 G5 server (Fedora 13) with two SAS disks in a hardware RAID 1, working fine.
Now I hot plugged another SAS disk. I'd like to configure this new hard disk out of my RAID, as a single non-RAID disk (ex. /dev/sdb).

Even after rebooting the server, I can't see the new disk with "fdisk -l". It displays only my hardware RAID, but not the new disk.

```
[root@myserver]# fdisk -l
Disco /dev/cciss/c0d0: 300.0 GB, 299966445568 bytes                           

        Disposit. Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id Sistema
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1   *           1         126      512000   83  Linux
/dev/cciss/c0d0p2             126       71798   292422656   8e  Linux LVM

Disco /dev/dm-0: 234.9 GB, 234881024000 bytes
Disco /dev/dm-1: 10.5 GB, 10536091648 bytes
Disco /dev/dm-2: 21.0 GB, 20971520000 bytes
Disco /dev/dm-3: 31.5 GB, 31474057216 bytes
Disco /dev/dm-4: 1577 MB, 1577058304 bytes
```

However, I can see the new disk using the HP Array Configuration Utility CLI for Linux "**hpacucli**":

```
[root@myserver]# hpacucli

=> controller slot=0 physicaldrive all show status

   physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, 300 GB): OK
   physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, 300 GB): OK
   physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, 300 GB): OK

=> controller slot=0 pd all show detail

Smart Array P400i in Slot 0 (Embedded)

   array A

      physicaldrive 1I:1:1
         Port: 1I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 1

      physicaldrive 1I:1:2
         Port: 1I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 2

   **unassigned**

      physicaldrive 1I:1:3
         Port: 1I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 3
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: **Unassigned Drive**
```

As  you can see, I've got two SAS disks in a RAID 1 and the new disk as "unassigned". Is there any way to work with the new disk as another non-RAID single disk?

If relevant, I want to create a new partition in my new disk, format it with mkfs and mount it, but as I can't see it with fdisk, I don't know how to do it.

Thanks!

## Update

Finally, as @mvp suggested, I created a new RAID0 with a single disk (the new disk) and it worked like a charm. I did the following:

```
[root@myserver]# hpacucli
=> ctrl slot=0 create type=ld drives=1I:1:3 raid=0
=> ctrl slot=0 pd all show

Smart Array P400i in Slot 0 (Embedded)

   array A

      physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 300 GB, OK)

   array B

      physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
```

Comment: This looks like solution for your problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/29349/disabling-raid-feature-on-hp-smart-array-p400

Comment: Thanks mvp. I don't want to lose my current RAID1. I just want to be able to work with my current RAID1 and my new single disk (as a new partition). I found that maybe creating RAID0 with my new disk (yes, a RAID0 with a single disk) could be a solution.

Comment: In linked question there is mentioning of using RAID0 of just 1 drive - almost JBOD

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It looks at this could be what I'm looking for. I will try it and will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I stumbled across this old post during tag cleanup.  It looks like you merged the solution into the question.  It's gotten over 1,100 views, so there's a good chance of future traffic.  Please consider moving the solution to an answer (and accepting it).  That will indicate that the problem was solved, and help anyone else with a similar problem search for the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I would think that once you have a third disk, you wouldn't be talking about RAID 1 anymore (unless it is a hotspare).  Instead, RAID 1E (non-standard RAID level, RAID 1 with non-standard enhancements).  [Wikipedia's page on Non-standard RAID levels: section on RAID 1E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_RAID_levels#RAID_1E), whereas [Wikipedia's article on standard RAID levels, section on RAID 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_1) just mentions two drives.